# context.drawWindow not working with chrome , why?

Tags: google-chrome

here is my code

```
context.drawWindow(window, 0, 0, 100, 100, "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
```

this code is running in the content js of the chrome extension. but its not working

please help me i m stuck badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

context.drawWindow is a mozilla firefox-only thing.  They extended the canvas context.  In other words, this won't work for any other browser.